# Android - marketing SMS

Tags: android, sms

What will be the sender address of the marketing messages? For example, the marketing messages from airtel possess addresses like AT-Jobs, AT-notification, etc., Will it be their sender address?? Or the sender address will be any number?? For such messages what will be the returning string of SmsMessage.getOriginatingAddress() method?? Pls reply.

Comment: why don't u inspect and see whats its returning?

Comment: Is there any way to get the sender address of the SMS which is stored in inbox?

Comment: use a broadcast receiver and receive the message. so that u can get that through getOriginatingAddress()

Comment: Its returning the address only if it receives a message.. I have few marketing messages in my inbox already. How can I get the address of those messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't feel like parsing & testing - the sender will be "AT-Jobs", "AT-notification" etc. etc.

Edit:

You could probably use [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#isWellFormedSmsAddress%28java.lang.String%29) to check if the sender is a valid number.

Comment: I am trying to create a filter for marketing sms.  So is it just enough to check whether the sender address contains any alphabets?

Comment: Try PhoneNumberUtils in that case. It should cover your use case also.

Comment: Thank you :) I have never used this method.  So if I am not wrong it returns false if the SMS is a marketing one right?

Comment: Well, it will return `false` if the number is definitely going to fail miserably if you try to text it back - your examples would return false for instance. Nothing prevents a marketing firm from using a fake dialable number however - those would require user input to filter (i.e. user gets spam from a dialable number, selects spammy number in your app and you block that one also)

Comment: Hi!! Are u aware of this scenario? - If I get a marketing SMS, Its Sender name will be something like LT-Jobs, LT-Notification and the Sender address will be unavailable. Is it possible to retrieve that name and store in a string?